# simple sybase dynamic SQL question (i hope)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I am trying to use column names as variables in a sybase environment and I understand that a dynamic SQL call may be the way to go. ultimately I want to loop through a set of column names in a script because I did not want a repetitive script, but for now I just need to figure out the variable part. the following is the script I try but I get an error of Result Set not permitted in '< Batch Statement>' and I do not know why or what that means (sorry not much of a sql guy)

```
declare @column_name VARCHAR(32)
declare @sqlcmd VARCHAR(128)
select @column_name = 'c1'
select @sqlcmd = 'select ' + @column_name + ' from custom.export_temp'
EXECUTE  (@sqlcmd)
```

Comment: Is this the exact error you are getting?

Comment: sorry I think it got cut off the full error of Result Set not permitted in '<Batch Statement>'

Comment: Is `select C1 from custom.export_temp` giving you the correct result? It seems the error belongs to ` custom.export_temp'. Is `custom` your schema and `export_temp` is the table?

Comment: If I run the select statement everything is fine, it's just when it is through the  execute that I have the issue. Custom is the schema

Comment: Which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)? Please post the entire error message (error number, error message).

Comment: sql anywhere 16, the sql code is 946 looking it up on ASE: You attempted to execute a SELECT statement in a context where a result set is not permitted. is the description